Установка GitLab рядом с Apache на Debian
Есть сервер на Debian 12.
На нем стоит Apache2 (для работы NextCloud). Прописано отдельное доменное имя (условно cloud.mydomain.ru), а также 80 и 443 порты.
Поставил GitLab. У него прописано доменное имя git.mydomain.ru и 444 порт.
Не могу заставить их работать вместе.
По отдельности все работает, а вместе работает только Apache.
По идее, чтобы все красиво работало по HTTPS, нужно в Apache прописать перенаправление с git.mydomain.ru:443 на git.mydomain.ru:444.
Но по факту GitLab не открывается ни по какому адресу и ни по какому порту (даже по IP-адресу). Такое ощущение, что все запросы перехватывает Apache и все перенаправления идут также на него, хотя в настройках, вроде как стоит прослушивание только 80 и 443 портов.
В какую сторону копать чтобы запустить GitLab?
